# How you define pattern to find all expression in braces

Tags: java, regex

```
String input = (1+(4+5+2)-3)+(6+8)
```

How do you define regex which can give

4+5+2 and 6+8.

```
String pattern = "(\\([\d\\+\\-]\\))";
```

Doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool for this job.

Comment: @JoeC Not entirely clear, but in this situation, it looks OK because he doesn't need to balance nesting levels, he just needs the innermost substrings

Answer (score 0):

You could do `\(([^\(\)]+)\)` but it will only ever find the inner most things in parenthesis. You could have the following input

```
(1+(4+((5*2)+3)+2)-3)+(6+8)
```

and the result would be

```
Match 1
Full match  7-12    (5*2)
Group 1.    8-11    5*2

Match 2
Full match  22-27   (6+8)
Group 1.    23-26   6+8
```

you should try to not use regex if possible

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `(\\([\d\\+\\-]\\))` you have to use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) like `+` to repeat the character class and note that inside the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) the plus sign does not have to be escaped and also the hyphen does not have to be escaped as it is the last character of the character class.

You regex would then look like `(\\([\d+-]+\\))` but that would also include matching the outer parenthesis.

What you might do is put the capturing parenthesis on the inside so you match the outer ones and make the inner ones function as a capturing group so that the values you want to have are in this group.

The character class `[\d+-]+` will also match for example `---` which I think is not what you want. You could for example first match digits and then a repeating pattern that matches either a `+` or `-` and then again digits to keep the structure of the expression. For example:

```
\\((\\d+(?:[+-]\\d+)+)\\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:[+-]\\d+)+` Non capturing group which matches a `+` or `-`, then 1+ digits and is repeated 1+ times.
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqougf/1)